# WKWebView is not loading url

Tags: ios, swift, macos, wkwebview

`WKWebview` is not loading certain urls. this is my code snippet

```
let myURL = URL(string: "https://contents.tdscpc.gov.in/")
let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
webView.load(myRequest)
```

when I change the url to say *`URL(string: "https://www.ndtv.com/")`* it works . Not sure why? any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59391866/810466

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First check did you set the permission in the info.plist file ? If not then you just need to take permission of **TransportSecurit** to **YES** in `info.plist` file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Like below

[image]

Answer (score 12):

## Mac App Devs

If you are building an app for the Mac, make sure to turn `App Sandbox` <kbd>ON</kbd> in your target and tick `Networks` Incoming/Outgoing Connections.

[image]

---

Update: If you prefer the long way, add the following to <kbd>YourAppName.entitlements</kbd>

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: Updated @Moritz - downvoting is a bit harsh :) Hope that makes you happier with the update!